# Understanding Javascript Variable Initialization

Tags: javascript, architecture, jquery

I saw this piece of code while doing research for an idle game I am making:

```
var minions = new Object;
minions = {
    0: {
        name: "Mole",
        description: "...",
        price: 10,
        priceModifier: 1.5,
        attributes: {
            goldPerSec: 1
        }
    },
    1: {
        name: "Bulldog",
        description: "...",
        price: 1e3,
        priceModifier: 1.5,
        attributes: {
            goldPerSec: 70,
            diamondsPerSec: .5
        }
    },
    2: {
        name: "Giant Ant",
        description: "...",
        price: 1e5,
        priceModifier: 1.5,
        attributes: {
            goldPerSec: 700,
            diamondsPerSec: 3
        }
    },
    3: {
        name: "A.W.E.S.O.M.-O 2000",
        description: "...",
        price: 1e6,
        priceModifier: 1.3,
        attributes: {
            goldPerSec: 5e3,
            diamondsPerSec: 20
        }
    },
    4: {
        name: "Caterpillar",
        description: "...",
        price: 8e7,
        priceModifier: 1.3,
        attributes: {
            goldPerSec: 3e4,
            diamondsPerSec: 100
        }
    },
    5: {
        name: "Pterodactyl",
        description: "...",
        price: 19e8,
        priceModifier: 1.3,
        attributes: {
            goldPerSec: 85e3,
            diamondsPerSec: 400
        }
    },
    6: {
        name: "Miner Spaceship",
        description: "...",
        price: 29e9,
        priceModifier: 1.3,
        attributes: {
            goldPerSec: 5e5,
            diamondsPerSec: 2700
        }
    },
    7: {
        name: "The dwarf King",
        description: "...",
        price: 3e11,
        priceModifier: 1.3,
        attributes: {
            goldPerSec: 3e6,
            diamondsPerSec: 16e3
        }
    },
    8: {
        name: "Spirit Golem",
        description: "...",
        price: 5e13,
        priceModifier: 1.3,
        attributes: {
            goldPerSec: 25e6,
            diamondsPerSec: 98e3
        }
    }
};
```

And I have a small idea of what is being done here but my question is how would this code be handled or triggered.

Really all I need is the name for what this is, and I can take it from there :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking at is an in-line initialization of an associative array (which functions similarly to a [dictionary](https://xlinux.nist.gov/dads//HTML/dictionary.html) or [map](https://xlinux.nist.gov/dads//HTML/map.html) in other languages).  If you made a variable in javascript like so:

```
var phones = {};
```

Then added *values* (right hand side) to *keys* (after the dot on the left)

```
phones.Steve = '2342311';
phones.Kyle = '3230009';
```

You will have an associative array (technically everything in javascript is an associative array but lets move on) with two keys.  If you've never used them, read about [javascript arrays](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/javascript/2865-javascript-data-structures-the-array-object.html).  Continuing on to what you're seeing, my same 3 lines of code can be written like this:

```
var phones = { Steve: '2342311', Kyle: '3230009' };
```

Now, the *keys value pairs* are inside of brackets and separated by commas.  When you see something like your example:

```
minions = {
0: {
    name: "Mole",
    ...
    attributes: {
        goldPerSec: 1
    }
```

`0` is a key for `minions` with a value of another array (this concept is known in languages as a *nested array* or *two dimentional arrays*).  `attributes` is an even more deeply nested array.

To use all of this, say you wanted that `goldPerSec` value, you'd retrieve it like this:

```
var gps = minions[0].attributes.goldPerSec;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed Thank you very much.

Comment: @Akmedrah No problem.

Comment: Minor correction, you can't access an object attribute that's a number using the dot notation. min.0 won't work, while min[0] will.

Comment: There are no associative arrays in JavaScript. There are [Arrays](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp) which are numerically indexed, and there are [Objects](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp). I think you should rename Associative Array to Object in your answer to avoid confusion.